# Co-occurrence of elements in collections

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, idioms

I have an Array of Arrays of Strings like

```
#(#('smalltalk' 'pharo' 'cool')
  #('smalltalk' 'pharo' 'new')
  #('smalltalk' 'cool'))
```

and want to count the co-occurrencies of Strings in the different collections, so I would get the following information:

> smalltalk, pharo, 2
>   smalltalk, cool, 2
>   smalltalk, new, 1
>   pharo, cool, 1
>   pharo, new, 1
>   cool, new, 0 (0 occurences are optional)

What would be the *most idiomatic* use of Smalltalk's (Pharo's) collection methods to gather this data? (The result could be stored in some simple object with element1, element2 and count variables.)

I can come up with some simple solution, but as with similar problems in the past, I find, that I miss a beautiful Smalltalk solution and do some stupid loops instead.

Comment: What solution did you come up with? You mentioned it's simple, but what makes you think it's not *idiomatic*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing that idiomatic, this is a relatively complex operation, I would decompose into these operations (prototype code) :

```
countAssociatedPairsIn aCollection
    | set pairs |
    set := aCollection flattenAllElementsInto: Set new.
    pairs := set generateAllPairs.
    ^pairs collect: [:pair | pair -> (aCollection count: [:associations | associations includesAll: pair])]
```

If you want to sort by count, then it's just another sortedBy: #value

If you just print but not collect:, you can turn some loops in do:

It remains to implement flattenAllElementsInto: (easy, something like flattened asSet), and generateAllPairs (or some kind of allPairsDo: if you just print, there is SequenceableCollection>>#combinations:atATimeDo: which is convenient enough for this task).

```
countAssociatedPairsIn aCollection
    | items |
    items:= aCollection flattened asSet asArray sorted.
    items combinations: 2 atATimeDo: [:pair |
        Transcript cr;
            print: pair; nextPutAll: '->';
            print: (aCollection count: [:associations | associations includesAll: pair]);
            flush]
```

Comment: Note that this answers the initial question which asked for 0 occurrences (cool, new, 0)

Comment: Yes, I changed the question, as I can live without the 0 occurences for my real-worls-problem. But perhaps that was a bad idea for Stack Overflow. I really like your answer, thank you!

Comment: I put the 0 occurences back to the question as optional.

Answer (score 4):

This gives also the reverse occurences, but I am fine with it.
It looks very legible to me, now the question is, if it is efficient:

```
|source bagOfPairs|

source := #(#('smalltalk' 'pharo' 'cool')
  #('smalltalk' 'pharo' 'new')
  #('smalltalk' 'cool')).

bagOfPairs := Bag new.
source do: [ :each | 
    each allPairsDo: [:first :second |
    (first = second) ifFalse: [bagOfPairs add: {first . second}]
    ].
].
bagOfPairs inspect.
```

Comment: Ah, but you do not get the 0 occurrences that you initially asked?

Comment: Yes, I changed the question, as I can live without the 0 occurences for my real-worls-problem. But perhaps that was a bad idea for Stack Overflow. I really like your answer, thank you!